# join tables in doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying join the tables, in Doctrine2 Query Builder. This was my query to join the two tables and get the result.

Initially i have two tables to be joined:

--> employees
--> org_employees

Other tables:

--> users

Here in my Doctrine2 Query builder code, i have joined 2 tables to fetch the results of  particular Organization employees by passing the Organization id.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM org_branch_employees oe
LEFT JOIN employees e ON oe.employee_id  = e.id
WHERE 
oe.org_id = 1;
```

By using the Query Builder the above sql code has been changed like below.

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('oe', 'e', 'o')
            ->from('Employee\Entity\OrgEmployee', 'oe')
                ->leftJoin('oe.organization', 'o')
                ->leftJoin('oe.employee', 'e')
                ->where('oe.organization = :organizationId')
                ->setParameter('organizationId', $orgId);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $orgEmployees = $query->getResult();
        return $orgEmployees;
```

This is my Employee Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Employee\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Users\Entity\User;
use Organization\Entity\Organization;

//use Organization\Entity\OrgEmployee;

/**
 * Description of Employee
 *
 * @author Macwin
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="employees")
 */
class Employee extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *     targetEntity="Users\Entity\User"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="user_id",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     nullable=false
     * )
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="employee_code", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $empCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *     targetEntity="Organization\Entity\Organization"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="org_id",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     nullable=false
     * )
     */
    private $organization;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Employee\Entity\OrgEmployee", mappedBy="employee")
     */
    protected $orgEmployee;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Employee\Entity\OrgEmployeeDesignation", mappedBy="employee")
     */
    protected $orgEmployeeDesignation;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->organizations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getOrganizations() {
        return $this->organizations;
    }

    public function addOrganization(Organization $organization = null) {
        $this->organizations->add($organization);
    }

    public function setUser(User $user = null) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getEmpCode() {
        return $this->empCode;
    }

    public function setEmpCode($empCode) {
        $this->empCode = $empCode;
    }

    public function setOrganization(Organization $organization = null) {
        $this->organization = $organization;
    }

    public function getOrganization() {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    function getOrgEmployeeDesignation() {
        return $this->orgEmployeeDesignation;
    }

    function setOrgEmployeeDesignation($orgEmployeeDesignation) {
        $this->orgEmployeeDesignation = $orgEmployeeDesignation;
    }

     public function getOrgEmployee() {
        return $this->orgEmployee;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
    }
}
```

Here is my OrgEmployee Entity Which maps the Organization table and Enity table, to get the Organization details and Employee Details.

```
<?php

namespace Employee\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Employee\Entity\Employee;
use Organization\Entity\Organization;

/**
 * Description of Org Employees
 *
 * @author Macwin
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="org_branch_employees")
 */

class OrgEmployee extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Employee\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="orgEmployee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    protected $employee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization\Entity\Organization", inversedBy="orgEmployee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="org_branch_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $organization;

    public function setEmployee(Employee $employee = null)
    {
        $this->employee = $employee;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmployee()
    {
        return $this->employee;
    } 

    public function setOrganization(Organization $organization = null)
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }    


}
```

Here is how i am getting the Organization details and Employee Details:

```
'employeeCode' => $orgEmp->getEmployee()->getEmpCode(),


 userFirstName =  $orgEmp->getEmployee()->getUser()->getFirstName(),
```

Being, employees table has mapping of users table, i can fetch the users information,

so far so good, but while i am trying to join more tables here, i couldnt bring the exact result.

But when i need to make the filter in the above functionality, i am not sure, how can bring the exact result.

Like filter by employee_code, user first name.

Can anyone guide me to bring the result. I am working on the REST API side to give the result to the client. Pagination was also there in the functionality.

I am trying the following if i am rightly said:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM org_branch_employees oe
LEFT JOIN employees e ON oe.employee_id  = e.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.id 
WHERE 
oe.org_id = 1 AND 
u.user_first_name = "John" and 
e.employee_code = "EMP777"
```

Answer (score 2):

So the first query is working as needed?  You just need to join the user entity and add some where conditions?  Or maybe I misunderstood the problem.

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('oe', 'e', 'o', 'user')
  ->from('Employee\Entity\OrgEmployee', 'oe')
  ->leftJoin('oe.organization', 'o')
  ->leftJoin('oe.employee', 'e')
  ->leftJoin('e.user','user')

  ->andWhere('oe.organization = :organizationId')
  ->setParameter('organizationId', $orgId),

  ->andWhere('user.user_first_name = :userFirstName')
  ->setParameter('userFirstName', 'John'),

  ->andWhere('e.employee_code = :employeeCode')
  ->setParameter('employeeCode', 'Emp666');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```